# how to create a 'root menu' with 'sub menu' in oritinal wagtail admin navigation bar?

Tags: wagtail

all:
i am a newbie to wagtail. recently, i programmed a wagtail engineering to manage some node mgmt toolkits. 
But on the navigation bar, i can ONLY make the single menu, by 'register_documents_menu_item' in wagtail_hooks, as picture shows.  How can i make some menus with sub-menu support?  and how does the dependence relationship work?  i've worked several days trying to use has_child method and insert js in html templates. but seems it all not works.

my wagtail environment is on:
wagtail 1.13.1
django 1.8

thanks for your help in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCQpQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

For multi-level menus, the Wagtail Menus package works very well:

https://wagtailmenus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Good luck!